# Finding parameter interval for closed curve in folium of Descartes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What would be an analytical approach to showing that the parameter interval of the parametrized closed curve $\left(\frac{3t}{1+t^3}, \frac{3t^2}{1 + t^3}\right)$of folium of Descartes is $t \in [0, \infty)$? I can only come up with an argument that the starting point is the origin $(0, 0)$, and as the parametrized curve is closed, we can examine for which $t$ the parametrized point reaches/approaches the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of the closed loop portion in the first quadrant as corresponding to $t \in [0,\infty)$ certainly seems to suggest letting $\theta \in [0, \pi/2)$ and $t = \tan \theta$.  Then if we can find a function $r(\theta)$ such that $$(r(\theta) \cos \theta, r(\theta) \sin \theta) = \left(\frac{3 \tan \theta}{1 + \tan^3 \theta}, \frac{3 \tan^2 \theta}{1 + \tan^3 \theta}\right),$$ we can express the folium as a polar curve whose distance from the origin is $r(\theta)$ for the respective angle $\theta$.  Such a condition is easily met, since $$r^2 (\theta) =  \frac{9 (\tan^2 \theta + \tan^4 \theta)}{(1 + \tan^3 \theta)^2} = \left(\frac{3 \tan \theta \sec \theta}{1 + \tan^3 \theta} \right)^2.$$
All that remains is to show that $$r(\theta) = \frac{3 \tan \theta \sec \theta}{1 + \tan^3 \theta} = \frac{3 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta}$$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ has zeroes only at $0$ and $\pi/2$, is strictly positive otherwise, and has but one critical point.  The first claim is obvious.  The second is also straightforward, since $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are positive for $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.  The last claim follows from the derivative:
$$r'(\theta) = \frac{(\cos \theta - \sin \theta)(\cos^4 \theta + \cos^3 \theta \sin \theta + 3 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta + \cos \theta \sin^3 \theta + \sin^4 \theta)}{(\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta)^2},$$ and the numerator is zero if and only if $\sin \theta = \cos \theta$ or $\theta = \pi/4$.  This shows the loop has a unique maximum distance from the origin.  Finally, there is symmetry, since $r(\theta) = r(\pi / 2 - \theta)$.